# How to plot a seaborn pairplot in an existing figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want seaborn to do a pairplot in an already defined figure. However it creates a new figure when sns.pairplot is called.

For example, the following code creates two figures, the first blank and the second containg the pairplot.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,9))
g = sns.pairplot(iris, hue='species')
```

The reason I want to use the existing figure is so that I can change the figsize and other figure attributes easily. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`rcParams`](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) to specify figure attributes:

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=(9,9)
```

then plot without calling `fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,9))`.

You can not set existing `fig` instance according to [FacetGrid](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/axisgrid.py) class of seaborn. You can control figure size by number of columns and rows and with `size` and `aspect` arguments of pairplot. `FacetGrid` calculate figure size as  `figsize = (ncol * size * aspect, nrow * size)`.

Comment: Thanks Serenity. I replaced the `fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(9,9))` line with `plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=(9,9)` and it worked ok. But ran a second time (using spyder) with `plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=(4,4)` and there was no change to the figure size.